# How do I update 2 Columns in 92 MySQL Rows at once

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I need to update **2 columns** in **92 rows** with unique values in a MySQL table with frontend HTML and backend PHP. Please note that, all the rows have unique ids. I think, It can be done easily using loops. But I'm not familier with loops since I'm very new to this field.

It may be a duplicate question, but I didn't get any proper solution from the duplicate questions. That's I'm posting this.

**Here's my frontend part:**

```
<table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Column 2</th>
                  <th>Column 3</th>
                  <th>Column 4</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

        <form method="post" action="process.php">

        <?php
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,column2,column3,column4 FROM records");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$column2,$column3,$column4);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $id ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $column2 ?></td>

                  <!-- Here User will input values for the below two fields in all the 92 rows -->

                  <td><input type="text" name="column3[<?php echo $id; ?>]"/></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="column4[<?php echo $id; ?>]"/></td>


                </tr>
        <?php } ?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update all">
                </form>
                </tbody>

    </table>
```

If anyone can guide me how do I update the "column3" and "column4" fields in all the rows at once, I'll be appreciated.

**process.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        foreach($_POST['column3'] as $key=>$value AND $_POST['column4'] as $key=>$value1){

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE records SET column3 = ?, column4 = ? WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('sss',$value,$value1,$key);
            $stmt->execute();

        }

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Done!";
            exit();
        }

}

?>
```

Comment: Do all 92 rows have the same id? What columns get the random values?

Comment: @chris85 No.. All the rows have unique ids. And I didn't get your second question.

Comment: The random values are going into `column3` and `column4`? Your `WHERE id = ?` limits the update to one row... or do you want to update all other rows after this row is updated?

Comment: @chris85 The user will input values for that two columns against the ids.

Comment: your loop is creating 92 separate forms. create one form and use HTML arrays to pass all values to process.php and then in process.php get that values from $_POST array and loop through each query.

Comment: @MurtazaBhurgri Can you please show me...?

Comment: @MurtazaBhurgri I have updated my question.. Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a hidden array input field with value as the *id*  needed later in `UPDATE` query in HTML form. This way the user does not see it or affect it. Then on submission, iterate through the `count` of `$_POST` arrays.

**HTML** *(in while loop)*

```
<td><input type="text" name="column3[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="column4[]"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hiddenfield']); $i++) {
     $key = $_POST['hiddenfield'][$i];
     $value1 = $_POST['column3'][$i];
     $value2 = $_POST['column4'][$i];

     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE records SET column3 = ?, column4 = ? WHERE id = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param('sss', $value1, $value2, $key);
     $stmt->execute();
  }

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Done!";
        exit();
    }
}
```